# Cant enable disable the buttons dynamically

Tags: office-js

We have an add-in to Office365/Office2016 which helps archiving office document into our own repository (content server). Users can initiate content management related operation using add-in command which are shown as ribbon button onto the office ribbon.
This operation includes importing document\email into repository, exporting from repository and showing up into office application etc.

While the add-in command helps initiating operation into the add-in perfectly fine, we do not see these add-in buttons can be dynamically enabled\disabled on the ribbon. These buttons are static and can only be added and removed using only manifest file which is not a feasible solution. This was the case with office thick client COM based add-in. While this functionality is missing in officeJS. Please advise.

Comment: As you already stated you cannot do that with Office.js API, what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea, but it is not currently supported. Please add votes to the request at Office Developer Voice: [dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13225365-support-dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon), which includes your requested new functionality.

Comment: Thanks Rick and Slava! Will vote as per your suggestions.  Is there a workaround currently to achieve this?